# Both the opamp terminal have tied to the same AC signal

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image][image]Both the opamp terminal have tied to the same AC signal.
what is the exact behavior of this circuit, and what is configuration name for this circuit??

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: Analyze it. You have V2 on the positive input, right? Because there is infinite resistance there, no current in R11. Also the opamp is in negative feedback circuit, so on negative in you have V2 as well. So no current there too. That means, no current on R7, so you get V2 on the output. It's a buffer.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum --- ok sir i got this point but i have  one more doubt regarding above same. If  i Connect one switch from +VE (non inverting terminal) to a GND. and that switch is closed(short to GND) for every -VE half cycle will it invert to  -VE peak cycle in to +VE peak?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. In engineering it's like in the court of law- every word matters. That are the switches you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Using the classical calculation methods for opamp based circuits it is easy to show that the closed-loop gain Acl for the shown circuit - independent on the parts values - always is Acl=+1.

Therefore, we are free to select the feedback path - and the loop gain - according to the stability requirements (phase margin). For this reason, we also can use opamps that are not unity-gain compensated.

Comment: When the switch is closed, R11 has no function and the circuit resembles the classical inverting amplifier with gain Acl=-R7/R10 .

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more on the second paragraph? Does this circuit reduce bandwidth like other compensation schemes do to tame non-unity-gain-stable opamps?

Comment: Just without calculation: R11 plays no major role, hence V+=Vin. For ideal opamps: V+=V-. Therefore, when V+=V-=Vin there is no current through R10 and also no current through R7. Thus: Vout=Vin. Second question: Yes, you are right. When the loop gain is reduced (with the aim to improve stability) the closed-loop bandwidth is, of course, also reduced to a frequency where the loop gain is unity. That is the price we have to pay for the advantage to have closed-loop unity gain with good stability properties.